# Partitionning the rdf datasets by subject in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a newbie to functional programming language and I am trying to  learn spark scala
The goal is to partition the rdf datset by subject
the code is below:

```
object SimpleApp {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

     val  sparkConf =
       new SparkConf().
         setAppName("SimpleApp").
         setMaster("local[2]").
         set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

     val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

     val data = sc.textFile("/home/hduser/Bureau/11.txt")
     val subject = data.map(_.split("\\s+")(0)).distinct.collect

  }

}
```

So I get to recover the subjects but it returns an array of string  also mapPartitions(func) and mapPartitionsWithIndex(func) : the func need to be iterator
So how do I proceed?

Comment: can you add a sample of your input file and the output it generates?

Comment: my input file is an rdf dataset in the format of Ntriples:for each line we have the subject,the object and predicate  and  for the output it generates:HashPartitioner cannot partition array keys.

Comment: please mark answer as correct if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioning your RDD by subject would probably best be done by using a HashPartitioner. The HashPartitioner works by taking an RDD of N-tuples and sorting the data by key eg

myPairRDD:

```
("sub1", "desc1")
("sub2", "desc2")
("sub1", "desc3")
("sub2", "desc4")

myPairRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2))
```

becomes:

partition 1:

```
("sub1", "desc1")
("sub1", "desc3")
```

partition 2:

```
("sub2", "desc2")
("sub2", "desc4")
```

Therefore, your `subject`s RDD should probably be created more like this (note the extra brackets which create a tuple/pair RDD):

```
val subjectTuples = data.map((_.split("\\s+")(0), _.split("\\s+")(1)))
```

See the diagrams here for more info: https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/19/shufflling-and-repartitioning-of-rdds-in-apache-spark/